# Получение текста между тегами <h1> и </h1>

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не могу получить текст между тегами `<h1>` и `</h1>`.

Делаю так:

```
preg_match('#<h1.*[^>]*>#i', $this->getContent(), $tag);
```

Но мне нужен только текст тега, а также нужно проверять наличие класса у тега.

Comment: А почему только регулярным выражением? Это ненадёжно, слышали о ["catastrophic backtracking"](http://habrahabr.ru/post/131915/)? Другие варианты принимаются?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильнее будет воспользоваться dom парсером, если в php хотите делать. Например [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php)

Но если очень хочется RegEx

```
<h1(.*(class="(?P<class>.+)"?).*|)>(?P<text>[^<]+)<\/h1>
```

[**Демо и описание**](https://www.regex101.com/r/hE4aR6/1)

Comment: Это регулярное выражение [не очень точное](https://www.regex101.com/r/hE4aR6/2). Осторожнее с точкой. Да и зачем лишний раз экранировать `<`?

Comment: Я думаю, что всяко регулярку можно обмануть :) В общем-то можно было остановиться в ответе на первом предложении, но автор хотел регулярку

Comment: @stribizhev про экранирование совершенно точно, перестарался :)

Answer (score 1):

```
/<h1[^>]*>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/h1>/i
```

И взять первую группу.