# Вывести h1 произвольной записи на Главной

Tags: php, wordpress

Как вывести h1 произвольного поста на главной (WordPress)? Нижеуказанный код выводит с помощью get_the_title() именно заголовок записи, а не h1.

```
<?php
$home_cats_ids = get_field('home_cats_ids', get_option('page_on_front'));
if ($home_cats_ids)
    $cats_ids = implode(",", $home_cats_ids);
else
    $home_cats_ids = '6,7,8';
// Вывод случайных материалов на главной
query_posts(array(
    'showposts' => 3,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'cat' => $home_cats_ids,
));
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>

/* Здесь нужно вывести h1 записи вместо заголовка записи*/
<?php echo get_the_title() ?>

<?php
    endwhile; endif;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: h1 этот находится я так понимаю в контенте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), который производит разбор html-кода.

```
<?php
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$home_cats_ids = get_field( 'home_cats_ids', get_option( 'page_on_front' ) );
if ( $home_cats_ids ) {
    $cats_ids = implode( ',', $home_cats_ids );
} else {
    $home_cats_ids = '6,7,8';
}

// Вывод случайных материалов на главной
get_posts( array(
    'showposts' => 3,
    'orderby'   => 'rand',
    'cat'       => $home_cats_ids,
) );

if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();

        /* Здесь нужно вывести h1 записи вместо заголовка записи */
        $content = get_the_content();
        $html    = str_get_html( $content );
        $h1      = $html->find( 'h1', 0 )->plaintext;

        ?>
        <h1><?php echo esc_html( $h1 ); ?></h1>
    <?php

    endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Кроме того, в коде я заменил `query_posts()` (использование очень опасно и крайне не рекомендуется) на `get_posts()`. Также вместо `wp_reset_query()` - `wp_reset_postdata()`.

Comment: Эм.... `<? the_title('<h1>', '</h1>'); ?>` Тоже самое только короче

Comment: @Walfter и ещё 31 способ...

Comment: Ну да тут согласен, это WP...

Comment: Но это выводит то же самое. Текст не меняется. Только семантика и стили.

Comment: @ОлегНечаев дык где h1 этот находится? В контенте? Доп поле? Это заголовок или что?

Comment: Этот код выводится на главной. А нужно дернуть h1 из рандомных статей блога.

Comment: Вы объясните тогда, что вы понимаете под h1. Общепринятое понимание - это тег h1.

Comment: То, что находится внутри тега h1

Comment: @ОлегНечаев https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431719/Получение-текста-между-тегами-h1-и-h1

Comment: Внутри тега h1 где - в контенте записи?

Comment: @ОлегНечаев только в вашем случае надо искать наверное в `get_the_content()`

Comment: Да, в контенте случайной записи. Нужно поместить вместо <?php echo get_the_title() ?> в коде выше то, что выведет содержимое h1

Comment: Спасибо! По неизвестной причине get_the_content() выводит все, кроме h1. По вышеуказанному способу выходит парсить h2 (если он существует в записи), а h1 нет (его после парсинга не существует). В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Так не бывает. Дайте пример контента с h1, при котором не работает.

Comment: http://dev.medcentrperm.ru/
Это главная. Здесь сейчас внизу страницы выводит h2 (установил h2, так как h1 не выводится).
http://dev.medcentrperm.ru/food/veggies/redka.html
Это статья.

Comment: Ну а с чего вы решили, что h1 в контенте записи??? покажите эту страницу в админке

Comment: Да, он не находится в контенте записи. Каким образом можно достать h1, который находится вне контента? Это содержимое single.php https://pastebin.com/zgVxP9RA

Comment: В коде написано же `<h1> <?php echo get_the_title();?>` - это заголовок записи

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79937/discussion-between-kagg-design-and--).